# When function is called from observer, error that “TypeError ... is not a function” happens

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

When function is called from observer, error that “TypeError ... is not a function” happens:

```
selected_project_id : {
              type: Number,
              observer: '_selected_project_idChanged'
},


...
_selected_project_idChanged(selected_project_id) {
                      this.some_function();
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: this.some_function is not a function at HTMLElement

Answer (score 0):

Type of the parameter should be Object:

```
selected_project_id : {
                  type: Oblect,
                  observer: '_selected_project_idChanged'
    },
```